# Не устанавливается PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pip, установка

При установке PyQt5 через pip выдаётся ошибка

```
pip install pyqt5
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.9-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (6.8 MB)
Collecting PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.11 (from pyqt5)
  Using cached PyQt5_sip-12.12.2.tar.gz (123 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting PyQt5-Qt5>=5.15.2 (from pyqt5)
  Using cached PyQt5_Qt5-5.15.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (50.1 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyQt5-sip
  Building wheel for PyQt5-sip (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for PyQt5-sip (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'PyQt5.sip' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyQt5-sip
Failed to build PyQt5-sip
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyQt5-sip, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Непонятно, что конкретно требуется для установки PyQt.Вресия pip последняя, версия Python 3.12.

Comment: Обнови `setuptools`: `pip install --upgrade setuptools`. Если не поможет — попробуй посмотреть [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261546/how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-or-greater-is-required-when-inst)

Comment: И кстати, какая у тебя стоит ОС?

Comment: Спасибо. Установщику PyQt действительно нужны были инструменты VS на 6 ГБ.

Comment: Вариант с установкой инструментов Virtual studio рабочий

Comment: Можно временно откатить Python до версии 3.11, пока основные библиотеки не обновятся.